# Excel downloads as ZIP

Tags: html, excel

We have a Excel sheet embeded in HTML page. And when a user clicks on it, it should get downloaded to his workstation. I had embeded the following code for this.
But when I click on the Excel sheet icon, it gives me the pop up window, with New_User_Checklist.zip option. Ideally what we should get is the pop up windows for the actual excel file New_User_Checklist.xlsx with options to open or save.

What is wrong with the code? Please suggest.

```
   <li>
    The checklist for the User Add
    <a href="manuals/New_User_Checklist.xlsx"><img src="icons/XLS-File-icon.png"
    border="0" hspace="10" /></a>
   </li>
```

Thanx in adv.

Comment: I think you forgot to post the code.

Comment: Excuse me...Is there now please.

Comment: What browser are you testing this in?

Comment: Internet Explorer 8  and the other links such as PDF on the same page having similar code ..work OK.

Comment: Based on some Googling, I think this is a browser-specific issue. Here is a link that may help you: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?162526-Is-your-docx-file-turning-into-a-zip-SOLUTION

Comment: what web server is this on?

Comment: This is Apache 2.2 and I tried to put the latest mime.types and reload apache but that did not help.

Comment: I tried with Netscape and it works without any problem. So is it a IE problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to some quick research, this issue may be browser specific, and I think it can be resolved by including a `.htaccess` file in your root directory (if you're running Apache). More information at [this](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?162526-Is-your-docx-file-turning-into-a-zip-SOLUTION) link.

According to one user there, you would need to add a line like this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet xlsx
```

Comment: We are using mime.types file. And I added the relevant entry like the 1 above. Reload apache but it does not work.

Comment: I'm not really an expert on this, but I would start by adding all of their suggested code to the `.htaccess` file and then narrow it down to what you need by removing a line at a time.